# How to add two event for the On submit

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

How to add react typescript  forms in the two events for the  onSubmit

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.onSaveMybus}> and  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
```

Anyone know how to add this correctly

Comment: Write another function and put those two inside

Comment: you should make function that make call to both function and then call it on submit of form

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Form onSubmit={() => {this.onSaveMybus();this.handleSubmit()}>
```

you can call this way two function at a time in react

Answer (score 0):

You can't call  onSubmit two times, so call other method from first onSubmit method.

```
const onSaveMybus = () => 
{
    // perform some task here

    handleSubmit();
}

const handleSubmit = () => 
{
   // perform some other task here
}

<Form onSubmit={onSaveMybus}></Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const firstFunction = () => {
 ...doFirstStuff
}

const secondFunction = () => {
 ...doSecondStuff
}

const onSaveMybus = () => {
   firstFunction()
   secondFunction()
}

<Form onSubmit={onSaveMybus} />
```